# What is a "Java Bean"?

Tags: java, definition, javabeans

The name really throws me off. I'm hoping someone can explain it in a way I won't forget :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean

Comment: Question can be extended to -  why "bean" in name JavaBean. How they posses any properties to "bean" ? Not sure though it will increase probability of question getting closed saying "not programming related"

Comment: Why Sun always show coffee bean while they market JavaBeans? Also why "tea cup" for marketing Java.

Comment: @Xinus, not sure if you are joking but in case this is a case of lack of insight into American slang, "Java" is slang for "coffee" here.  Hopefully that makes all of the coffee references clearer.

Comment: You should NOT confuse Java Beans (plain objects following some simple conventions) with Java Enterprise Beans. The later are a way of implementing business logic in an 'enterprise application' (and are in their own world).
I think the Java Bean term was coined for using this kind of simple, propertied object with UI designers, allowing a Property Editor to discover and manipulate its state.
But a lot of frameworks like beans...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Any serializable java class (implementing java.io.Serializable)  that follows specific conventions: a  no-argument constructor, and properties accessible via get/set/is accessors.

The idea is to make it predictable, so that properties etc can be discovered automatically through reflection - of great help in tool and framework development.

Comment: Beans do not constitute very elegant OO-design since it is essentially a data structure without any behavior, and it completely exposes its innards. See domain-driven design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design and http://domaindrivendesign.org/resources/what_is_ddd

That said, most designs rely on bean-like classes to represent their model so it is the de-facto standard way of approaching this.

Comment: Not adhering to DDD does not mean it's not "elegant OO design". It's not like Eric Evans owns the concept of objects. The fact is, if you want to make a data grid (a common, arguably not elegant gui) and not make your domain objects aware of it, properties are as elegant as it gets.

Comment: There's nothing in JavaBeans, by definition or convention, that says they are "a data structure without any behavior".  In fact, there's [a standard interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/AppletInitializer.html) which is for helping to instantiate "JavaBeans that are also Applets", and I think we can all agree that Applets have behavior!

Comment: Would be rad if you explained what `Serializable` actually means

Answer (score 15):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean

> JavaBeans are reusable software components for Java that can be manipulated visually in a builder tool. Practically, they are classes written in the Java programming language conforming to a particular convention. They are used to encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean), so that they can be passed around as a single bean object instead of as multiple individual objects. A JavaBean is a Java Object that is serializable, has a nullary constructor, and allows access to properties using getter and setter methods.
>
> [continue reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) »

[image]

Comment: Esko, when the question is this simple, I don't see the harm in quoting Wikipedia.

Answer (score 9):

JavaBeans are reusable software component written in java.The components can be configured and connected using builder tools.Three key properties that causes any class in java to become a javabean is

```
1.Class is serializable
2.class has a 0 argument constructor
3.class has getter and setter methods for data members
```

Here is a simple class that is eligible for becoming a javabean

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable {

    private String name = null;

    //0 argument constructor
    public Student() {
    }
   //getter method
   public String getName() {
        return name;
   }
   //settor method
   public void setName(final String name) {
       this.name = value;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

> [***Sun's*** JavaBean Tutorial says...](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/whatis/index.html)
>
> The JavaBeans™ architecture is based on a component model which enables developers to >create software units called components. Components are self-contained, reusable software units that can be visually assembled into composite components, applets, applications, and servlets using visual application builder tools. JavaBean components are known as beans.
>
> A set of APIs describes a component model for a particular language. The JavaBeans API specificationdescribes the core detailed elaboration for the JavaBeans component architecture.
>
> Beans are dynamic in that they can be changed or customized. Through the design mode of a builder tool you can use the Properties window of the bean to customize the bean and then save (persist) your beans using visual manipulation. You can select a bean from the toolbox, drop it into a form, modify its appearance and behavior, define its interaction with other beans, and combine it and other beans into an applet, application, or a new bean.

If you've used Swing's 'button', then you've used a component (visible JavaBean).  You can use developers tools (like NetbeansIDE) to change the Bean's available 'properties'.  Netbeans uses something called 'introspection' to discover which JavaBean *properties* can be modified by the coder/user (e.g. *name*, *text-title* and *alignment* for a Swing Button JavaBean component).  You can save its state too (the IDE/Beans developer might use 'serialization' to do this) allowing re-use with your favourite settings another time.

JavaBeans don't need to be visible (like a swing component).  You could create your own JavaBean to encrypt text in a textbox when someone clicks an 'OK' button on a form.  You don't see your custom written JavaBean, but some other developer could re-use your 'encryption' JavaBean in their code with some 'property' changes that you allowed to be public (i.e. encryption-type="blowfish").

Regards,
SteJav

Answer (score 5):

A java bean is a class that is serializable, has a no-argument constructor, and uses getters and setter methods for its member fields. Its used in Java Enterprise Apps to store business logic data.

Answer (score 4):

A JavaBean is a Java object that satisfies below programming conventions:

1. The JavaBean class must implement Serializable Interface
2. The JavaBean class must have a no-arg constructor which should be public
3. All JavaBean properties must have public Setter and Getter methods to set and get all bean properties.
4. All JavaBean instance variables should be private and only accessible by Getter and setter.