# Beans in java programming

Tags: java

What are beans in java programming?Is having an understanding of Struts vital for learning Spring?

Comment: have you even tried to ask http://www.google.de/#q=java+beans+example or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean ?

Comment: Not at all its generic not limited to Javabeans

Comment: I don't know that it is a dupe; they're asking about Spring beans too.

Comment: About your second question: Struts and Spring do not have anything to do with each other. So no, an understanding of Struts is not vital for learning Spring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends.

You could be talking about Spring beans, Enterprise Java Beans or some other variant.

The general answer is that beans are some type of generic object (or POJO perhaps) that hold information - almost think of them like their own data type. The distinction is that they typically don't have much in the way of behaviors eg, they only have: simple fields, getters, setters.

Comment: thanks what then is a beanfactory?

Comment: Typically a class which hands out bean instances. Are you working with Spring?

Comment: yes should i learn struts before spring?

Comment: I'm not really sure if it would be best to learn struts or Spring first, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean):

> JavaBeans are reusable software
>   components for Java that can be
>   manipulated visually in a builder
>   tool. Practically, they are classes
>   written in the Java programming
>   language conforming to a particular
>   convention. They are used to
>   encapsulate many objects into a single
>   object (the bean), so that they can be
>   passed around as a single bean object
>   instead of as multiple individual
>   objects. A JavaBean is a Java Object
>   that is serializable, has a nullary
>   constructor, and allows access to
>   properties using getter and setter
>   methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973073/what-is-a-java-bean

Answer (score 4):

Java Bean is a class that conforms to the following convention:

- The class must have a public default constructor (no-argument). This allows easy instantiation within editing and activation frameworks.
- The class properties must be accessible using get, set, is (used for boolean properties instead of get) and other methods (so-called accessor methods and mutator methods), following a standard naming-convention. This allows easy automated inspection and updating of bean state within frameworks, many of which include custom editors for various types of properties.
- The class should be serializable. This allows applications and frameworks to reliably save, store, and restore the bean's state in a fashion independent of the VM and of the platform.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean).

Comment: Thanks for expounding on the definition, for those of us not savvy with all the terms in it.

Answer (score 4):

A "bean"  can be everything, depending on context. Thus it is roughly equivalent to an "object". (Note that it can also be viewed as equivalent to "class", although I think it's more about instances than definitions. Hence "bean class" is more often used)

- a spring bean is any spring-managed object
- a javabean is an object of class the conforms to the javabean spec (properties, getters and setters)
- enterprise java bean is a container-managed object

As for your second question - no, struts and spring are rather separate technologies and neither of them requires knowing the other.

Answer (score 1):

Is having an understanding of Struts vital for learning Spring?
No, both follow the MVC pattern so knowing struts will help you to know spring..but otherwise there are lot of differences..in how the two work.

Comment: does that mean that i can go for spring without touching struts??

Comment: That is what I did, they are completely different projects not related, I just know the basics of struts, but spring I know much more..you don't even need to know that Struts exists to use Spring except may be that it is used more than Spring...